# Having trouble navigating file explorer with python

Tags: python, selenium

I am building an automated browser with selenium and it is working flawlessly! (thank you selenium (: )
But I am having trouble uploading a file. One of the steps I need to execute is to upload a file.

The code I use to upload, and seems like it works for many people, is:

```
file_input = driver.find_element_by_id('ImageUploadButton')
file_input.send_keys('C:\\image.jpg')
```

Also tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('ImageUploadButton').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type="file"]').clear()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type="file"]').send_keys('C:\\image.jpg')
```

This seems to work for a lot of people, but for me, it just opens the file explorer for me to pick the file I want to upload, and that is it. No error message, just continues to execute the code.

Is anyone aware of maybe another module that I can use to navigate the file explorer and submit the file?

Or am I using selenium inappropriately?

----------- edit ---------------

Added DIV from website:

```
    <div id="FileInputWrapper" class="file-input-wrapper">
    <input id="FileUploadInput" type="hidden" name="file">
    <button id="ImageUploadButton" class="button-update-cancel short file-upload-button" type="button" style="position: relative; z-index: 1;"> Select Images</button>
    </div>
<input type="hidden" name="images">
<div id="html5_1auv7g94u187l1qdq108d1ue5qve3_container" class="moxie-shim moxie-shim-html5" style="position: absolute; top: 518px; left: 0px; width: 155px; height: 45px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 0;">
<input id="html5_1auv7g94u187l1qdq108d1ue5qve3" type="file" accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif,image/bmp" multiple="" style="font-size: 999px; opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
</div>
```

Comment: I think you should click the upload button after having sent the path with send_keys.

Comment: It's hard to make suggestions without `HTML` code for target element. Update your question with proper code sample. Also clarify what you mean "work for many people"? Who are those people? Do they use your code successfully?

Comment: Yeah I agree, sorry, added HTML sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you use wrong locator to upload file. You should handle `input` element, not `button`:

```
file_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="file"]')
file_input.send_keys('C:\\image.jpg')
```

Comment: BTW, if anyone else is having the same issue:

Comment: My issue was "Do not click the element (driver.find_element_by_id('ImageUploadButton').click()) and I using the wrong locator as Andersson said.